# Which less popular shells do you use and what are their advantages?

Tags: shell

Apart from what you can (arguably?) call the more popular shells (bash, csh, Korn, zsh) what other ones do you know and use and what unique features do they have?

ps - One answer per shell would be ideal to gather a meaningful survey

Answer (score 8):

I'm currently using `zsh`, but I believe it's the new trend in shells. I haven't gotten down and dirty with it so far, but as far as i can tell it has nifty autocompletion support, right-side prompt, multiline command editing and some other nifty stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I like [fish](http://fishshell.com), although I rarely use it myself. It's tremendously helpful for beginners who haven't met sh and think bash is unfriendly.

Comment: I installed Fish to play around with it at one point, but am in the process of updating my Linux box, so I haven't reinstalled it. I was honestly impressed by it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [tcsh](http://www.tcsh.org/Welcome) for years.  Its backwards compatible with csh, but adds a bunch of useful features like command completion, command history, etc.  This is just for interactive use.  For scripting, I don't think there is any reason to use anything other than bash.

Comment: `tcsh` is hard to use for those who are used to Bourne shell as it is descendant of `csh` and behaves differently then Bourne shell descendants (like bash, zsh etc.).

Comment: @Maciej You are right.  I wouldn't recommend switching to anyone already used to a Bourne shell descendant.  I started out with csh, and haven't found a good reason to switch.

Comment: I started on tcsh and still like it better than bash.  But I eventually had to port my default shell over to bash because I keep logging into systems which didn't have tcsh.  Where as bash is pretty much everywhere (at lease in Linux).